# Reporting through e-mail if PHP script crashes

Tags: php, error-handling

I have some php scripts for importing product feeds into a website. Sometimes those scripts crash (due to the "500 Internal Server Error", I believe) and I need to send a notification through e-mail.

Will it be sufficient to add a `try catch` to the existing code? Something like:

```
try {
[existing_code]
}

catch (customException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
  [e-mail_the_error]
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: 500? Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2146171/1301076

Comment: What PHP function are you using to retrieve the product feeds?

Comment: @ amrhady: I'm using custom made functions, it will take too much space to paste them here. Usually they work, but there are moments when the server load is high and the scripts are dumped.